# Boost asio async_receive/write don`t receive/send package correctly. after 0x00 will write 0xfe

Tags: c++, boost, server, asio

I have a server:

```
receive_socket->async_receive(boost::asio::buffer(receive_buffer[1], MAX_SIZE_PACKAGE),
        boost::bind(&ClientServingLogic::receive_event, this, 1,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
```

And have a client:

```
void send(const char* text, int length) {
    if (length > BUFFER_SIZE)
        return;
    strcpy_s(buffer_sender, length, text); //buffer_sender has enough memory
    boost::asio::write(*socket_sender,boost::asio::buffer(buffer_sender, length));
}
```

////////////////////////////// using client

```
char subscribe[] = { 0x55, 0x03, 0x00, 0x11,
                    0b10001000,
                    0b00010000,
                    0b00000001,
                    0b00000000,
                    0b00000000,
                    0b00000000,
                    0b00000000,
                    0b00000000
                    };

client.send(subscribe, 15);
```

So, when i trying use this code, it`s work correctly by first 0x00. After that in buffer will contain only 0xFE values 12 times. Memory of server buffer (receive_buffer[1]) after receive:

```
0x000001DA89F70160  55 03 00 fe fe fe fe fe  U..ююююю
0x000001DA89F70168  fe fe fe fe fe fe fe 00  ююююююю.
```

First 3 symbols was received correctly including 0x00. but after that i get 0xFE, that length of 12;

How to receive whole data correctly?

Comment: `strcpy_s` stops when it hits a '\0', you probably wanted `std::memcpy` instead. Unrelated: 15 is larger than your data (12), so you probably want to fix that too.

Comment: Oh, yeah. You are right. I forgot this stuff about strcpy_s (((( Thanks!